# C, comparing arrays, find a character,

Tags: c

So I am kinda new to coding, but what I want to do is write a string, write one character I wish not to be in the string if it occurs. I've tried using `removedChar = getchar()` instead of `fgets(removedChar, 2, stdin);` but then I can't do the `!=` in the `if` statement.

I would really appreciate your help.

```
int main() {
    char str[20], removedChar[2];
    int i, n, j;

    printf("ENTER A STRING:");
    fgets(str, 20, stdin);
    printf("ENTER WHAT CHAR YOU WISH TO REMOVE: ");
    fgets(removedChar, 2, stdin);

    n = strlen(str);
    for (i = 0, j = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (strcmp(str, removedChar) == 0) {
            str[j] = str[i];
            j++;
        }
        if (str[i] == ' ') {
            str[j] = str[i];
            j++;
        }
    }
    str[j] = '\0';
    printf("string after removing character = %s", str);

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `fgets` includes the return at the end.

Comment: You're missing `#include <stdio.h>`, `#include <string.h>` and `#include <stdlib.h>`.

Comment: @RadLexus Not if the buffer is too small for it.

Comment: I got the # includes, just forgot to copy them!

Comment: What `!=` are you talking about? There is no `!=` in your code.

Comment: It looks like you're deeply confused about what `strcmp(str, removedChar) == 0` means. It tests whether the string `str` is equal to the string `removedChar`.

Comment: @melpomene: I thought of mentioning that ... seems  OP knew this and deliberately set `removedChar` to be 2 characters long only. (Although I'm pretty sure that return will pop up later and cause some bewilderment.)

Comment: So if you have the string `sasquatch` and you want to remove the character `s`, do you have to remove both instances of `s`, or just the first one found?

Comment: All instances of s.
About the != part, I would like to use (str != removedChar) but that does not work. Even if I use removedChar = getchar() instead of the fgets I still get a problem in the if statement for (string != character).

Comment: "that does not work" or "I get a problem" aren't problem descriptions. Tell us what actually happens.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly this line:

```
if (strcmp(str, removedChar) == 0)
```

is comparing if two strings are identical. Please see [`strcmp`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strcmp.htm).

You need to instead compare character against characters, instead of equality of string against string.

Having said this, you can now just simply loop over the string, and use `!=` to rule out matching characters, and update the string accordingly with a counter.

Additionally, it is always safe to check the return value of [`fgets`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fgets.htm), and also check that you havn't exceeded the buffer length.

This is the code that uses these ideas:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define STRSIZE 20

int
main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    char str[STRSIZE];
    int i, j, removedchar;
    size_t slen;

    printf("Enter a string: ");
    if (fgets(str, STRSIZE, stdin) == NULL) {
        printf("Error reading string\n");
        return 1;
    }

    slen = strlen(str);

    if (slen > 0) {
        if (str[slen-1] == '\n') {
            str[slen-1] = '\0';
        } else {
            printf("Error: Exceeded Buffer length of %d.\n", STRSIZE);
            return 1;
        }
    }

    if(!*str) {
        printf("Error: No string entered.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Enter what character you wish to remove: ");
    removedchar = getchar();

    if (removedchar == '\n') {
        removedchar = ' ';
        printf("No character was entered. Spaces will be removed if found\n");
    }

    j = 0;
    for (i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if (str[i] != removedchar) {
            str[j++] = str[i];
        }
    }
    str[j] = '\0';

    printf("Changed String = %s\n", str);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: For those who wonder how `strlen(str)` can return `0` if `fgets()` did not return `NULL`, it is possible if there is a `'\0'` byte at the beginning of a line in the input stream. This is not easy to enter for the terminal, but a carefully crafted input file could take advantage of this possibility to crash the program or at least invoke undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `str[i] != removedChar[0]` instead of using `strcmp()` which compares the full strings.

Also note that you should strip the newline character from the string read by `fgets()`.

Here is a corrected version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char str[80], removedChar[80];
    int i, n, j;

    printf("ENTER A STRING: ");
    if (!fgets(str, sizeof str, stdin))
        return 1;
    str[strcspn(str, "\n")] = '\0';  // strip the newline character if present

    printf("ENTER WHAT CHAR YOU WISH TO REMOVE: ");
    if (!fgets(removedChar, sizeof removedChar, stdin))
        return 1;

    for (i = 0, j = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if (str[i] != removedChar[0]) {
            str[j] = str[i];
            j++;
        }
    }
    str[j] = '\0';
    printf("string after removing character = %s\n", str);

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```